# LEFT Function in an autofilter criteria

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm attempting to use the LEFT function to cut the last few numbers off of a value to be used in an auto filter function (end user uses differently formatted data than the database).

I have my code below and it works fine without the LEFT function in the criteria part, but am having trouble with the syntax/declarations(?).

```
'
        Dim C2 As Variant
        C2 = Worksheets("Display Page").Cells(2, 3).Value

        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic   'Restarts automatic calculations so that tables can be filtered and data pull formulas can be run
'
        Sheets("Database").Range("B$24:BKL71499").AutoFilter Field:=WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("D2"), _
            Worksheets("Car Park 19-21 BDDS").Range("B23:BL23"), 0), Criteria1:=Left(Cells(C2), 5).Value
'
        Application.Calculation = xlManual      'Restarts manual calculations only for workbook speed
End Sub
```

Without quotations around C2, I get a 424 object required error, with them I get an error 5 invalid procedure call or argument error. Not using a variable there at all gives error 424 as well.

This just leads me to believe it's my syntax that's wrong :\ but I can't find anything online that is similar enough for me to adapt it so it works in this situation.

Comment: Criteria1:=Left(Cells(C2), 5).Value , could you change it to  Criteria1:=Left(Cells(C2).value,5)

Comment: That worked! Thanks very much Pasumpon!